# Proving that $(R/I) \otimes_R A$ and $A/IA$ are isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

"Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ be a right ideal, and $A$ be a left $R$-module. Prove that $(R/I) \otimes_R A \cong A/IA$ as groups, where $IA$ is the subgroup of $A$ generated by $\{ra \mid r \in I, a \in A\}$."

I'm thinking that I need to start with a map $\phi: (R/I) \times A \to A/IA$, show it's middle-linear, and then use the universal property of tensor products to obtain a unique group homomorphism $\overline{\phi}: (R/I) \otimes_R A \to A/IA$ such that $\overline{\phi} \circ i=\phi$ ($i$ is the canonical $R$-middle linear map in this case.)

Where I'm struggling is how to actually define my starting map $\phi$. Should I do something like $\phi(r+I,a)=ra+IA$? How would I show well-definedness? Any hints/explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the exact $R$-module sequence $0\to I \to R\to R/I\to 0$; tensor with $A$ to get a right-exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
  A\otimes_R I\overset{f}\to A\otimes_R R\overset{g}\to A\otimes_R R/I\to 0
\end{equation*}
$A\otimes_R R \cong A$, and thus $A/\ker g\cong A\otimes_R R/I$. But the sequence is exact at $A$, so $A/\ker g \cong A/\textrm{im} f$. $\textrm{im} f$ is the image of $A\otimes_R I$ in $A\otimes_R R$, which is obviously $I A$. Thus the sequence
\begin{equation*}
  0\to I A\to A\to A\otimes_R R/I\to 0
\end{equation*}
is exact.

Comment: I’d have to look back at some material involving exact sequences, but your response makes sense. I appreciate your help!