# Proof verification of showing that $M\otimes A/{\frak a} \cong M/{\frak a}M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products, module-isomorphism

Let $A$ be a (commutative) Ring with $1$. Let $M$ be an $A$-Module and ${\frak a}\subseteq A$ an Ideal.

I was trying to prove that $M\otimes A/{\frak a} \cong M/{\frak a}M$.

I would like to know whether my attempt is reasonable and if not, what i need to take more care of.

I just considered the "obvious choices" via \begin{align*} \varphi\colon M\otimes A/{\frak a} &\to M/{\frak a}M \\ m\otimes (a+\frak a) &\mapsto am+{\frak a}M\end{align*}

and its inverse as

\begin{align*} \psi\colon M/{\frak a}M  &\to M\otimes A/{\frak a} \\m+{\frak a}M   &\mapsto m\otimes(1+{\frak a})\end{align*}

In order to confirm they are indeed inverses of each other, i argued as follows:

$$(\varphi\circ\psi)(m+{\frak a}M) = \varphi(m\otimes (1+{\frak a})) = 1\cdot m + {\frak a}M = m + {\frak a}M$$

\begin{align*}(\psi\circ\varphi)(m\otimes(a+{\frak a})) = \psi(am+{\frak a}M) &= am \otimes (1+{\frak a}) \\ &= am \otimes 1 + am \otimes \frak a \\ &= {\color{red} {m\otimes a + m\otimes a{\frak a}}} \\ &= m\otimes a + m\otimes \frak a \\ &= m\otimes (a+\frak a).\end{align*}

I didn't include checking for well definedness, but i'm aware that i need to confirm that the maps i've chosen are indeed well defined. This post is more about the way i chose the respective maps.

---

My questions:

1. Is my attempt more or less reasonable? Or did i do some technical errors? I'm a bit uncertain about the red part.
2. Would it be necessary to invoke the homomorphism theorem in order to justify the existence of $\psi$ in the first place?

Thanks for any advise and help!

Comment: could I ask, what course this is taken from? is it Rep theory or module theory? Also, what's $M$? Could you elaborate a bit more please :)

Comment: It's just abstract algebra (module theory).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826475/27542 provides a slightly different approach as well.

Comment: This is a solution-verification post, i wanted to have feedback for my own proposed solution, thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For well-definedness of the maps you can just use the universal property of tensor products for $\varphi$, and define $\psi$ on $M$ and show that elements of $\mathfrak aM$ go to zero. The maps you have specified are good.

One thing to keep in mind is that general elements of $M\otimes (A/\mathfrak a)$ are *sums* of pure tensors. But your argument is still fine since the sums will just pull out of the maps since they're homomorphisms.

The calculations you're doing around the red part are essentially correct, although you should keep the "$+\mathfrak a$" part on the right side of the tensors since the right side of the tensor is in $A/\mathfrak a$. You can also just do $$(am)\otimes(1+\mathfrak a)=m\otimes(a(1+\mathfrak a))=m\otimes (a+\mathfrak a).$$

---

Answers to comments:

The universal property is exactly what's used to justify the map you gave $M\otimes (A/\mathfrak a)\to M/\mathfrak a M$ is well-defined. So you would consider the map $M\times (A/\mathfrak a)\to M/\mathfrak a M$ via $(m,a+\mathfrak a)\mapsto am+\mathfrak a M$ and show that this is $A$-bilinear, and the universal property gives you a unique $A$-linear map $\varphi:M\otimes (A/\mathfrak a)\to M/\mathfrak a M$ which satisfies $\varphi(m\otimes (a+\mathfrak a))=am+\mathfrak a M$. Basically when you want to send a pure tensor $x\otimes y$ to some $z$, you use the universal property and first define a bilinear map which sends $(x,y)$ to $z$.

For showing $\psi$ is well-defined you don't need the first isomorphism theorem (I assume this is what you mean by the isomorphism theorem). You just show that $\mathfrak a M$ is *contained* in the kernel of the map $M\to M\otimes (A/\mathfrak a)$ via $m\mapsto m\otimes(1+\mathfrak a)$, so that this map factors to a map on $M/\mathfrak a M$. You could also just directly check that your map $\psi$ is well-defined, but this will be equivalent to what I have described here (and what I have described would be a little cleaner).

Comment: Thanks @Dave. I wasn't sure whether $a{\frak a}$ is indeed equal to $\frak a$ but this should be true since for an ideal $\frak a$ it holds that $a\cdot a_i$ for $a\in A$ and $a_i\in \frak a$ is contained in $\frak a$ and therefore $a{\frak a} = \frak a$ holds, right?

Comment: That's right: $a\mathfrak a=\mathfrak a$ because of the "multiplicative stickiness" of ideals. Note that $\mathfrak a=0+\mathfrak a$ is the zero element of $A/\mathfrak a$, so the second term in your red part is actually just $m\otimes (0+\mathfrak a)=0$.

Comment: Thanks Dave! That's incredibly helpful. Highly appreciating your comments.

Comment: Another Question if you don't mind @Dave, i was wondering, does the universal property of the tensor product make it possible to define an $A$-bilinear map explicitely on $M\times A/{\frak a} \to M/{\frak{a}}M$ and from there induce my $A$-linear map $M\otimes A/{\frak a} \to M/{\frak{a}}M$ with the exact same image points?

You mentioned i could define $\psi$ on $M$ and show that the kernel is ${\frak{a}}M$ but that would basically be invoking the homomorphism theorem, so i'm wondering if i also could avoid using the homomorphism theorem and immediately define an $A$-bilinear map?

Comment: I added answers to these questions in the body of my post.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks Dave, your answers are really clarifying things. What i refered to as homomorphism theorem is basically just the factor theorem (namely, that the quotiened out part is indeed contained in the kernel). 

One last question: If i'd decide to check the well-definedness by hand, would it suffice to check whether ${\frak a}M$ is contained in the kernel or would i also need to ensure that my map does not depend on the choice of a representative?

Comment: Checking it directly means showing it is independent of choice of representative, so take $m+\mathfrak a M=n+\mathfrak a M$ and show that they map to the same thing under $\psi$. You can try this out for yourself, and I think you'll be able to see how it ends up being equivalent to just showing that the map $M\to M\otimes (A/\mathfrak a)$ has $\mathfrak a M$ contained in its kernel.

Comment: Beautiful, i'll immediately get my hands on it. Thanks for all your help Dave. Accepting your answer of course.

Answer (score 1):

A rather different way to prove this is by using the Yoneda Lemma. We have the following isomorphisms, natural in $B$:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Hom(M \otimes A / a, B) &\cong \Hom(A / a, \Hom(M, B)) \\
&\cong \{f \in \Hom(A, \Hom(M, B)) \mid \forall a \in {\frak a}, f(a) = 0\} \\
&\cong \{g \in \Hom(M, B) \mid \forall a \in {\frak a}, a \cdot g = 0\} \\
&= \{g \in \Hom(M, B) \mid {\frak a} M \subseteq \ker g\} \\
&\cong \Hom(M / {\frak a} M, B)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

And therefore $M \otimes A / {\frak a} \cong M / {\frak a}M$ by the Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution Mark.